# How to change Spock Mock's behaviours outside of a specification?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, spock

As an addendum to my other question: [How to create Spock mocks outside of a specification class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810646/how-to-create-spock-mocks-outside-of-a-specification-class) - is it possible to change the behaviour of Mocks outside a specification?

In our project we have a lot of code in our Specifications that reads like this:

```
someService.findById(SomeMother.SOME_OBJECT.id) >> SomeMother.SOME_OBJECT
someService.findById(_) >> {throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such object")}
```

I would rather have code like

`Helper.register(SomeMother.SOME_OBJECT).to(someService)`

so i don't have to duplicate the mocking logic everywhere and. However it seems that I cannot change the behaviour of Mocks outside of a specification as the Mock simply registers the call instead of recognising that I want to change it's behaviour. Is there a way to do this or do I have to repeat all my initialisation logic over and over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

Today, the only way to share mocking related code between classes is via a base class. Once Spock supports Groovy 2.3 mixins, mixins will likely be the way to go.

If you find yourself sharing mocks a lot, consider using fake objects instead. Typically, mocks are very specific to the test at hand.